# emacs org-mode : continuous clocking does not work

Tags: windows, emacs, org-mode

I activated the option org-clock-continuously to recover gaps in my clocking and the continuous clocking does not seem to work.

I am often fixing endtimes for clocked items, because I forgot to clock out (using the function org-resolve-clocks and using the K option (keep x minutes).

When I am clocking in afterwards (in the agenda view) after having fixed the last clock, org-mode always clocks me in with the current time instead of the last time I clocked out (according to the clock resolution).

Example:

TODO sample todo

CLOCK: [2013-07-31 Mi 12:53]

M-x org-resolve-clocks -> K -> 5

CLOCK: [2013-07-31 Mi 12:53]--[2013-07-31 Mi 12:58] =>  0:05

agenda view: clock in  on a different task

(! no question, if I want to clock in now or at last clock out time !)

** TODO sample todo 2

CLOCK: [2013-07-31 Mi 13:22]

Any ideas how to fix this or what option I have to activate in addition to org-clock-continuously?

I am working on windows 7 Professional with GNU Emacs (GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)) and orgmode 8.0.3

Comment: I can't help directly, but are you clocking from the same session as the previous clock-out (ie you're not restarting Emacs inbetween)?I ask because according to the docs it only remembers the previous clocked-in entry from the same session.

Comment: I am always using the same session wihout restarting emacs

Comment: I also tested with org-mode 8.0.6 with the same behaviour